# Javascript/JQuery to validate the Radio button list in the Gridview at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my web page, I have a GridView, each grid view row contains a check box and a set of radio buttons in a column as shown in code. If a check box is selected, the radio buttons will be enabled to true to select as shown in screenshot image. At the bottom we have a submit button to save selected details. On button save click I need to validate the controls, like required field validator for radio buttons.
[image]

My problem is Javascript to validate the Radio button selection at the client side.

And I tried below Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
    function Validate() {
        var RB1 = document.getElementById("rdbPlans");
        var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var isChecked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked) {
                isChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isChecked) {
            alert("Please select an Plan");
        }
        return isChecked;
    }
</script>
```

//But it is not working.

And GridView Columns are

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ItemTemplate>                                                   

</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="name">
    <HeaderStyle Width="30%" />

</asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plans">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbPlans" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbPlan_OnSelectedIndexChanged" Enabled="false">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" Width="80px" runat="server" Text="0.00" Style="text-align: right"
            OnTextChanged="txtAmount_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false"
            CssClass="txtBox" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" Width="80px" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" Text="0.00"
            Style="text-align: right;" />
    </FooterTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="20%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />                                                    
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: show us what you tried in javascript/jquery? create a jsfilddle or jsbin with html output of gridview and script that you tried.

Comment: edit your question and update it with the code, then remove your comment. also create a http://www.fiddle.net/ with html output of your gridview.

Comment: Not this code. The HTML output of the gridview from browser. use Deveoper tools (F12) in chrome or in IE and update with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps, it may help you:

1. Defined public variable RadioButtonListClientIDs for storing dynamic generated RadioButtonList names with comma
2. Find the RadioButtonList on RowCreated event of GridView
3. get client id of RadioButtonList and store into RadioButtonListClientIDs with comma
4. Define javascript varialble as follow

   var rblistid ='<%=RadioButtonListClientIDs%>';
5. using split function you can convert array from rblistid.

   var rbid = rblistid.split(","),

   ```
   for (i = 0, l = rbid.length; i < l; i += 2) {

   $( "input[name=" + rbid[i] + "]:radio" ).each (function( index ) {
               alert(this.checked);
   });
   ```

   }

from above logic you will find all checkboxes and its status and you can proceed your validations

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     function Validate() {  
         var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");  // your gridview name here
         var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");  
         var flag = 0;  
         for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) { 

             if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {  
                 if (rbs[i].checked) {  
                     flag = 1;  
                     break;  
                 }  
             }  
         }  
         if (flag == 0) {  
             alert("Select One");  
             return false;  
         }  
         else { 
             var x= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
             if(x==true)
                return true;
                else
                {
                    if(document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>") != null)
                    document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").innerText = "";
                    return false;
                }
         }     
     }
```

check my article here for reference
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Dorababu742/using-radio-button-in-gridview/